# Checking header file for dependencies at compile-time

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, g++

Do compilers offer the capability to automatically check if each source file (and its associated header file, if any) include all other headers that are required? Or at least issue a warning, say, if a required header is not included explicitly?

For example, I would like the compiler to report when I do something like this:

header1.h

```
#include <string>
...
```

header2.h

```
#include "header1.h"
#include <iostream>
std::string blah;    //<-- issue warning here, <string> not included explicitly
...
```

source2.cpp

```
#include "header2.h"
...
cout << endl;        //<-- issue warning here, <iostream> not included explicitly
```

I am using g++ and Visual Studio, so my question primarily applies to these compilers. Thanks!

Comment: The compiler will tell you, but not that you forgot to include some particular file. You'll have to deduce this information from the error messages yourself.

Comment: When a compiler see's <string> included in header1.h it won't give any report when you use it in header2.h as you have already included header1.h in header2.h... I think doing that is perfectly ok as C++ doesn't like code duplication...

Comment: I wonder why two people down-voted this question. I would appreciate some input in the comments as to why they consider this question not constructive.

Comment: It's quite common to design header files so that including them is the official way to get declarations made in some other headers they include.  It's the case for instance of the standard library of g++, `string` is not declared in `<string>` but in `<bits/basic_string.h>`. There would be a lot of false positive or you'd need a mechanism to avoid them...

Comment: @DanNestor ur right buddy, looks like down voting is the latest trend... They wanna scare people before they post questions I guess...

Comment: The thing is, there is a very good reason why "implicit" inclusion is the norm: as a user of a library, you don't have to worry about which exact headers you need to include, the library's headers already "drags" them in. What you want would be a huge hindrance on programmers, to get rid of all the warnings one would have to manually include tons of "useless" headers already included by the library. Very bad idea (especially when compiling with `-Werror` aka. "treat warnings as errors").

Comment: Using `#pragma once` there is no performance degradation for including the same file multiple times, both directly and indirectly, so I would say this question is a premature optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic way for doing so, as far as I know.

My suggestion is to confine inclusions into headers only to what is needed for the "interface" defined in the .h
In C++ Coding Standards (Sutter, Alexandrescu) you can find an item which tackles this explicitly (it's titled Make header files self-sufficient). I cite:

> Behave responsibly: Ensure that each header you write is compilable standalone, by 
>   having it include any headers its contents depend upon

and

> But don't include headers that you don't need; they just create stray dependencies.
>   Consider this technique to help enforce header self-sufficiency: In your build, compile 
>   each header in isolation and validate that there are no errors or warnings.

Moreover you should always include your own .h first, since this maximizes the probability of finding out if there are inclusion errors.

In all cases, headers should be swappable, so that if your file includes a.h and b.h, both possible orders should do.

Comment: That is precisely the coding practice I am trying to adhere to, however I am wondering if the compiler cannot help in identifying potential problems. I am thinking that it should be trivial to adjust the translation unit so that these problems are found at compilation time.

Comment: As I said, as far as I know there is no such possibility. I can add that I would probably have known if there were, at least I suppose it would have been mentioned in C++ Coding Standards, since they write about this issue

Comment: @DanNestor: "precisely the coding practice I am trying to adhere to" - it's not the same as your question... when C++ Coding Standards says "by having it include any headers its contents depend upon" they don't necessarily mean *directly*, which is what your question is trying to enforce.

Comment: @DanNestor: that said, some judgement's useful: e.g. if you include a "string_utils" header that has lots of functions returning strings by value and includes `<string>`, then it would be redundant and verbose to include `<string>` yourself, but if you included a header than only incidentally used string - say having `f(std::string)`, then it's imaginable the maintainer may move to f(const std::string&) and use a forward declaration - doing users the "favour" of not having to include `<string>` if they weren't using that specific function - so if you had other uses of `string` you'd get burnt.